# RALLY REST API, unable to find type defination for custom field using internet explorer

Tags: rally

If I am using **Chrome** or **firefox** then I am getting type defination for custom field in the response of following [URL](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.41/typedefinition.js?pagesize=200&fetch=true)

but with the same URL I am not gettig the type defination on **internet explorer**.

Comment: Fiddler, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, will let you compare the web requests from the 2 browsers.  This will show you if it is a problem with the request, or a problem with how the response is displayed.

Comment: Do you get an empty page in IE or only the object related to the custom field is missing?

Comment: Nickm, object related to the custom field is missing.